# How inject a collaborator who needs a back reference into a constructor

Tags: object-oriented, javascript

Following Hevery's advice to inject collaborators into constructor rather than new'ing things within constructor body, how gracefully do this when a collaborator needs a back reference to its owner, without using an evil 'init' method (another violation of Hevery's best practices for testable code).

E.g.

```
    export class Model {
    constructor( history ) {
      this._history = history; // But history needs to know Model too
      history.model = this;    // Is it just as simple as this? Feels awkward
      ...
    }
    ...
   }
```

vs.

```
    export class Model {
    constructor() {
      this._history = new History(this); // But new'ing things here reduces testability
      ...
    }
    ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a case where you just need to `new` it up: create the instance in the constructor. If the two things can't exist without each other, and you don't need to utilize polymorphism, then there is no sense in passing the dependency in.

Otherwise you need to break the circular dependency between Model and History.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject a factory instead of a instance:

```
export class Model {
    constructor(HistoryFactory factory) {
      this._history = factory.createHistory(this);
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But I guess Misko would advise you to get rid of the circular dependency.